# Highcharts : On drillup, how can I unselect my selected point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, selection

I'm using a chart with drilldown and I've allowed to select a point (=click). On the event click, I create an HTML table with help of AJAX to list the entities related to the count (if I see 5 items, by clicking on it I'll see who are the 5 items and list them). This becomes a 2nd/3rd level of drilldown (depending I've clicked on the 1st level of 2nd level in the chart)

However, I'd like to remove the selection on first level on the drill up event.

Here is my code (EDITED) :

**Edit**
I'm adding series like this ([sample found here](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/pypaq94t/11/)) :

```
$(function() {
   var myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
           type: 'column',
           renderTo: 'drillDownContainer',

           // Deactivate drilldown by selection.
           // See reason below in the drilldown method.
           selection: function(event) {
                 return false;
           },
           drilldown: function(e) {
                    // Deactivate click on serie. To drilldown, the user should click on the category
                    if (e.category === undefined)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Set subTitle (2nd param) by point name without modify Title
                    // Giving 1st param as null tells the text will be for the subTitle,.
                    // For Title, remove the null 1st param and let text.
                    this.setTitle(null, { text: e.point.name });

                    if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                        var chart = this,
                            drilldowns = {
                                'Social': [
                                    {"name":"Serie 1","data": [{"id":113,"name":"my data","y":14}
                               ]}                                  
                           ]
                        };

                        var categorySeries = drilldowns[e.point.name];
                        var series;

                        for (var i = 0; i < categorySeries.length; i++) {
                            if (categorySeries[i].name === e.point.series.name) {
                                series = categorySeries[i];
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                        drilldownsAdded++;

                        // Buffers the number of drilldown added and once the number of series has been reached, the drill down is applied
                        // So, can't navigate by clicking to a single item.
                        // However, simply click on the category (xAxis) and then unselect the other series by clicking on legend
                        // The click has been disabled.
                        if (drilldownsAdded === 3) {
                            drilldownsAdded = 0;
                            chart.applyDrilldown();
                        }
                    }
                },
                drillup: function(e) {
                    this.setTitle(null, { text: '' }); // Erase subTitle when back to original view
                    $('#ajaxContainer').html(''); // Remove the table drilldown level3
                },
                drillupall: function(e) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(this.series);
                    console.log(this.series.length);

                    for(i = 0; i < this.series.length; i++)
                    {
                        console.log("i = " + i);
                        console.log(this.series[i].data.length);
                        for (d = 0; i < this.series[i].data.length; d++)
                        {
                            console.log("d = " + d);
                            console.log(this.series[i].data[d].selected);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
   }); -- End of myChartdeclaration

   myChart.addSeries({
                    color: colorsArray['impact101'],
                    name: '1-Modéré',
                    data: [
                        {
                            id: '101',
                            name: 'Type 1',
                            y: 64,
                            drilldown: true
                        },
                        {
                            id: '102',
                            name: 'Type 2',
                            y: 41,
                            drilldown: true
                        }]
                }, true);

});
```

Demo of the point selection : http://jsfiddle.net/8truG/12/

**What do I'd like to do? (EDIT)**
If I select a point on the 2nd level, then return to 1st level and then back to same drilldown data, the point selected before is not selected anymore. 
However, for the 1st level, the selection remains.

On the `drillup` event, the this.series[x].data[y] corresponds to the data of the 2nd level. Kind of obvious as the drilldown is not finished for all series but event raised as many as there is series.

On the `drillupall` event, I'm getting the right serie. I can see my 3 series on debug but they are all without any data. So I can't apply `this.series[i].data[d].selected` as suggested in comment below.

I'm using Highcharts 5.0.9.

Any idea to help me ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I don't understand everything with how you either show the table or actually drilldown... But why not just do an unselect on the point?

Comment: It would be great if you could give us more specific information about your idea because it is not so clear at the moment. I think that, as Halvor wrote, you should be able to use point.select(false) for unselecting your point: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point.select

Comment: Thanks both for your comment. I've edited my post and gave more code and explanation. Hope it's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got helped on the Highcharts forum. [See here](https://forum.highcharts.com/post134027.html#p134027).

Here is the answer (in case the link above doesn't work in the future):

> In this case you can change the state of a specific point with
>   Point.select() function. Take a look at the example posted below. It
>   works like that: in drillup() event there is a call of
>   getSelectedPoints() which returns all selected points from the base
>   series. Next, there is a call of select() function with false as an
>   argument on a selected point to unselect it. In addition, the call of
>   the getSelectedPoints() is located in a timeout, otherwise it would
>   return an empty array (see
>   https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5583).
>
> CODE:

```
setTimeout(function() {   selectedPoints =
     chart.getSelectedPoints()[0];  
     chart.getSelectedPoints()[0].select(false); }, 0);
```

> API Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Ch ... ctedPoints
>   http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point.select
>
> Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/smshk0b2/

Consequently, here now the code fixing the issue :

```
drillupall: function(e) {
                        this.setTitle(null, { text: '' }); // Erase subTitle when back to original view
                        $('#ajaxContainer').html(''); // Remove the table drilldown level3

                        var chart = this,
                            selectedPoints;

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints()[0];
                            // Ensure there is any selectedPoints to unselect
                            if (selectedPoints != null)
                            {
                                selectedPoints.select(false);
                            }
                        }, 0);
```

Regards.